# Laravel-permission Undefined type PermissionRegistrar

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-permission

I'm trying to install the package Laravel-permission v5 for a project in Laravel 8.

Following the instructions at the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel), I runned

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

and to be able to migrate the permission tables I executed:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider"
```

Instantly, in the file database/migrations/create_permission_tables.php it gives me the error

`Undefined type 'Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar`

What can I do? I'm new in Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import it in config/app.php ??

Try this:

```
 php artisan optimize:clear
 # or
 php artisan config:clear

 php artisan migrate
```

Comment: The command php artisan optimize:clear solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to recharge your vscode window:

tape: ctrl + shift + p
pass : Developer:Reload Window

finish with that particular problem

Answer (score 0):

Delete file permission.php in config folder

then run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider"
```